# Show element only once in report

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to access and trying to practice some fundamentals. I am trying to generate a report based on user input from a form.

When the user selects an address a report should be generated with one instance of the address.

As of right now when I create the report on the click from the form.
There are multiple instances been generated of the same address.

The table i am using

AddressLine1
123 Main St.
555 Happy Ln.
456 Main St.
6598 W Street St.

code:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub generateReport_Click()
    Dim text As String
    text = Me.custAddress
    DoCmd.OpenReport "Generation", acViewPreview, "AdressLine1=" & text
End Sub
```

The outcome is the following...

[![Report outcome][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wr1Zg.png

I only want it to be printed once.

Answer (score 0):

NVM fixed it by adding a wherecondition

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub generateReport_Click()

    Dim text As String
    
    text = Me.custAddress
    

    DoCmd.OpenReport "Generation", acViewPreview, text, _
        WhereCondition:="AddressLine1 = '" & text & "'"
    
    
End Sub
```